# Boost library file generation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I am trying to compile boost 1.52 library files with Visual studio 2013. To do so, run the file b2 with the visual studio prompt command.

Everything seems to run correctly . However, the lib files that I am getting in /stage/lib/ have no version of VC. For example, I have

```
  libboost_date_time-vc-mt-1_52.lib
```

My dynamic libraries require

```
  libboost_date_time-vc110-mt-1_52.lib
```

When I rename all files by substituing vc with vc110, it works as a charm, but it is a very fastidious process.

I made some researches and I could see that one could control the version of Boost with respect to the version of VS. I tried the following command

```
  b2 toolset=msvc-12.0
```

Yet, I still get the versionless file.

How do I make it work ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a more recent version of boost? I'm using 1.60, with option `toolset=msvc-14.0` for VS2015, and the file generated is `libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_60.lib`

Comment: Boost 1.60 is causing me other issues, that is why I downgraded to 1.52, which is a version that does the job. In the past , I could get the right file with boost 1.52 but I did not generate the boost lib files. 
Anyhow, I would expect boost to generate  lib files with a version number disregarding boost version .

Comment: `I would expect boost to generate lib files with a version number disregarding boost version`...exepct if the release where they started to do that is between 1.52 and 1.60...

Comment: Please tell me more in detail, I probably do not have the knowledge to get it right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boost 1.52 was released in 2012. At this time, Visual Studio 2013 was not an existing compiler.

You are compiling a library with a not officially supported compiler. You're actually even lucky that boost 1.52 compiled with Visual Studio 2013.

It's not surprising that b2 is unable to add `vc110` to your libraries names. There may be a case statement somewhere in boost build system configuration files that has a version name for every "supported" compilers....and there may be no vc110 there...

You need either to take the first boost version supporting Visual Studio 2013 or use Visual Studio 2010 compiler (which is supported by 1.52)....or rename the files manually as you did.

By the way, note that renaming the libraries will make auto-link fail if you are plannign to use it. See `boost\config\auto_link.hpp`: this explicitely handle every compiler version....will only work with officially supported compilers.